# Why can't my app be found in Google Play Store under its new name

Tags: android, google-play

I changed the name of my app in Google Play Console yesterday.  A new version has been published with the new name.  When I search the Play Store under the new name, it cannot be found.  But if I search under the old name, it is found, even though the new name is displayed.  I could understand if it was found under both the old and the new, but why can't I find it under the new name?
Original name:  Retirement Income Simulator.
New name:  Retirement Calculator.
Search on Retirement Calculator not found.  Search for Retirement Income Simulator and found listed as Retirement Calculator.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming related question within the scope defined by the [help/on-topic].

Comment: I thought it might be related to the overall programming of an app.  I am new to this and it is my first app.  I don't know where google is getting the name from, if comes from something in my build files, package naming or setup in Google Play Console (which is a platform for programmers).  Where can I get help otherwise?  I am on my own and have no programming friends.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I changed the name of my app in Google Play Console but when it didn't appear in the Play Store, I was worried that there was more I had to do, such as change the app name in the build gradle file or put something extra in the Manifest file.  It turns out, I just needed to wait a few days for the change to go through.  Updating the name in Google Play Console was all that was required.

Answer (score 0):

The Play Console does not work like you would expect. Even for normal updates of your application you could see that to some people the new version is not yet available.

When changing the name of the application this could take a while, because it depends on two things, one that you can control, one that you cannot control:

1. Cache of the play store on your device. If the info has been fetched for the app you are looking for, it could display the local cache. You can delete the data of the play store app to see if it helps.
2. Arquitecture of the Play Store distribution. The Play Store is not a single server that gets updated with all the things we developers do regarding our apps, its more like a decentralized set of nodes, so for some nodes the change is quick, but for others it may take a while. I guess you could say it works under the paradigm of eventual consistency.

So, to answer your question. Try to delete cache of the play store app and check if the name is updated. If not, don´t sweat on it, it could take a while.

Comment: Thank you Sergio for your kindness in answering my question.  Perhaps I am being too impatient and haven't given it enough time for the update to come through.  I am in Western Australia and everything takes forever to reach here, even COVID hasn't gotten in, so what chance Google?